# Huge docker image size with Ror based on ruby slim-bullseye and libvips-dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rails-activestorage, libvips

I'm using `ruby:3.1.3-slim-bullseye` to dockerize a rails 7 application.

The image size is about **2Gb** with no clear reason.

I'm using active storage which uses vips (that's why i use libvips-dev).

I tried to inspect image layers with `docker history`,
the output indicates two huge layers related to these docker commands.

```
RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential curl git libpq-dev  "

RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail && apt-get install -y libvips-dev"
```

Output for `docker history my_image --no-trunc`,

```
..... other entries 


sha256:bf2ec68f81ba5fea38089b6a09d60786f296776b76f8083c9e3c94eae64533f5   24 minutes ago   |3 GID=1000 NODE_ENV=production UID=1000 /bin/sh -c bash -c "set -o pipefail && apt-get install -y libvips-dev"       667MB

sha256:1f778f131d692203d3918ea0fbc8e91c2466fadc7bd42ac8d333b8cf34cdae2b   25 minutes ago   |3 GID=1000 NODE_ENV=production UID=1000 /bin/sh -c bash -c "set -o pipefail && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential curl git libpq-dev  "           258MB


...... other entries
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.1.3-slim-bullseye
WORKDIR /app

.... Other docker entries

#
RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail  && apt-get update "

RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential curl git libpq-dev  "

RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail && apt-get install -y libvips-dev"

RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail &&  groupadd -g \"${GID}\" ruby && useradd --create-home --no-log-init -u \"${UID}\" -g \"${GID}\" ruby"

RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail  \
  && chown ruby:ruby -R /node_modules /app \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /usr/share/doc /usr/share/man "

.... Other docker entries
```

What's wrong with `apt-get install` so it makes libvips-dev takes **667MB** and `build-essential curl git libpq-dev` took **258MB** ?

Comment: `build-essential` plus its dependencies does intrinsically wind up being very large; it includes a full C tool chain, compilers, headers, static libraries, &c.  A common technique is to use a multi-stage build to avoid including this in the final image.

Comment: (You do not need to explicitly say `bash -c` in every `RUN` command; Docker on its own wraps each `RUN` command in `sh -c`.  So _e.g._ `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...`)

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze for your feedbacks, will apply these changes to base image.

I tried with a simple dockerfile 

`FROM ruby:3.1.3-slim-bullseye

RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail  && apt-get update "

RUN bash -c "apt-get install -y libvips-dev"

ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]`

The layer for libvips-dev line is so huge.
[https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5431172/267487295-088474f4-e99d-46c5-a933-96fcdf4672bc.png](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5431172/267487295-088474f4-e99d-46c5-a933-96fcdf4672bc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on ruby-vips (https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips/issues/370#issuecomment-1716933820).

Here are the recommandations :

1 - Instead of installing `libvips-dev`, we can use plain `libvips`. (Don't know the exact reason for using the `libvips-dev` initially)

2 - Add `--no-install-recommends` to the command

So the command is `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libvips`

The image layer size now is **130MG** which is **ok** comparing to **667MB**